# How to create a Magento 2 Modal popup that cannot be closed?

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento-2.1, jquery, modal

I'm trying to create a modal popup that cannot be closed. It has a button that takes you to the next page by clicking on it, but I don't want users to be able to close it.

The modal popup can be closed in 3 ways:

1. Clicking the cross/`[X]` button in the top right corner
2. Pressing escape
3. Click on the *overlay*

So far this is my modal JS and I think with `clickableOverlay: false` I've already tackled the 3rd one:

```
require(
    [ 'jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal' ],
    function($, modal) {
        $("#popup").modal({
            autoOpen: true,
            responsive: true,
            clickableOverlay: false,
            modalClass: 'modal-custom',
            title: 'Popup',
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Take me back to the homepage'),
                class: 'action close-popup wide',
                click: function () {
                    window.location.href = '/';
                }
            }]
        });
    }
);
```

**UPDATE:**

I also tried to setup the modal in a different way when trying the provided solutions:

```
require(
    [ 'jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal' ],
    function($, modal) {
        modal({
            //options
        }, $("#popup"));
    }
);
```

Comment: 4. Use a developer tool to remove the inserted modal from the DOM

Comment: @KristofatFooman, hahaha, Ok, I'll add to the modal text: "Please press F12, inspect this modal and remove it from the DOM to close it". I think you're right, quite interesting one, but I'll accept that risk and not implement any measures to prevent that one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I couldn't get an override of the `modal.closeModal()` function to work via mixins and also I think doing it via a mixin makes it override through the whole website on all modals, which I do not want. I only need it on this one modal.

I ended up by simply removing any trigger that will call `modal.closeModal()`. There are some other modal options you can use to achieve that:

1. I hide the close button on opening the modal with the `opened` option/event which will be triggered right after the modal has been opened
2. I'm overriding the `keyEventHandlers.escapeKey` option

So this is my final code:

```
require(
    [ 'jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal' ],
    function($, modal) {
        modal({
            autoOpen: true,
            responsive: true,
            clickableOverlay: false,
            modalClass: 'modal-custom',
            title: 'Popup',
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Take me back to the homepage'),
                class: 'action close-popup wide',
                click: function () {
                    window.location.href = '/';
                }
            }],
            opened: function($Event) {
                $('.modal-header button.action-close', $Event.srcElement).hide();
            },
            keyEventHandlers: {
                escapeKey: function () { return; }
            }
        }, $("#popup"));
    }
);
```

Comment: Good job it's definitely the right way of doing it

Answer (score 7):

I reckon using mixins in that case would be relevant.

You can try the following:

First in your module, create the following `view/base/requirejs-config.js` :

```
var config = {
    'config':{
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal': {
                'Vendor_Module/hook':true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then create `view/base/web/hook.js` :

```
define([], function(){
    'use strict';    
    return function(targetModule){
        targetModule.closeModal = function(){
            return false;
        }
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

With this mixin, you replace the implementation of the `closeModal` method with your own method. In that case, returning false would avoid closing the modal.

> Side note: I hate you for doing this. Unclosable popups should be
>   banned from the web.

Comment: I did exactly that, but still it closes. If I run this in my terminal, I see that the mixin IS working: `jQuery.mage.modal.closeModal` gives me `function() {
            return false;
        }`

Comment: @7ochem maybe `return false;` is not enough. I'm not super at ease with JS to be honest. I reckon you should read this article it may help you narrow down the issue or finding another possible way of doing it: http://alanstorm.com/the-curious-case-of-magento-2-mixins/

Comment: I guess this also replaces the `closeModal()` function site wide, which I do not want. I only want to apply this to this single modal